# CURL not working when POSTING json to my Web Service

Tags: json, rest, grails, curl

I created a rest web service with Grails 2.3.x as below:

```
import grails.rest.RestfulController
class CityController extends RestfulController{

static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']
CityController() {
    super(City)
}
}
```

Here is my domain class:

```
import groovy.transform.ToString
import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode

/**
 * City
 * A domain class describes the data object and it's mapping to the database
 */

@ToString(includeNames = true, includeFields = true, excludes = 'dateCreated,lastUpdated,metaClass')
@EqualsAndHashCode
class City {

    /* Default (injected) attributes of GORM */
    Long    id
    Long    version

    /* Automatic timestamping of GORM */
    Date    dateCreated
    Date    lastUpdated

    String cityName
    String postalCode
    String countryCode // either iso2 or iso3



    static constraints = {
        postalCode blank:false, nullable:false
        cityName blank:false, nullable:false
        countryCode minSize:2, maxSize:3, blank:false, nullable:false, matches: "[A-Z]+"    
    }
}
```

and this is urlMapping

```
class UrlMappings {

static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }

    "/"(view:"/index")
    "500"(view:'/error')
    //
    // RESTService api
    "/api/city"(resources: 'city')
}
}
```

when I try to get my data with curl, I manage to get my result using this line:

```
curl -X GET -H "Accept:application/json" http://localhost:8080/ComuneUtenti/city
```

But when I try to post data to my WS, I run into an error as below:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: countryCode
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: postalCode
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 6
{"errors":[{"object":"comuneutenti.City","field":"postalCode","rejected-value":null,"message":"property [postalCode] of class [class comuneutenti.City] cannot be null"},{"object":"comuneutenti.City","field":"cityName","rejected-value":null,"message":"property
[cityName] of class [class comuneutenti.City] cannot be null"},{"object":"comuneutenti.City","field":"countryCode","rejected-value":null,"message":"property[countryCode] of class [class comuneutenti.City] cannot be null"}]}
```

here is my POST:

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d '{"cityName":"NewYork", "countryCode":"IT", "postalCode": "00166"}' http://localhost:8080/ComuneUtenti/api/city
```

What am I missing?

I am using Grails 2.3.10
The same WS can be called with Postman.

Thanks

Comment: Wrap your json with single quotes to prevent your shell from parsing it.

Comment: thanks, but I already tried so and I was getting the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try erichelgeson's suggestion?

The correct curl method is

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d '{"cityName":"NewYork", "countryCode":"IT", "postalCode": "00166"}' http://localhost:8080/ComuneUtenti/api/city
```

Notice the single quotes around the json payload.

To see what's really going on you can use the echo command.

```
$ echo {"hello":"world"}
{hello:world}

$ echo '{"hello":"world"}'
{"hello":"world"}
```

The shell is eating the quotes around your fields.

Comment: Try updating your question with the exact curl request you are using.  The one in your question is missing the single quotes around the JSON payload.

Answer (score 0):

What version of grails 2.3 are you using?
Grails 2.3.8 had a bug where you could not post to rest services.

I believe this was the checked in here.

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/commit/c050212fa0992f5b2d62c8e63795e4278fb2c3f4

Comment: thanks, but I am using 2.3.10 and I can post using Postman so it might be an error in my curl string command